# How do I check if the Javascript global object has been tampered with?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just had this really dumb bug that took 20m to find simply because I forgot the `var` keyword somewhere. I figured it out, but it just got me thinking...

"Is there an easy way to see if any properties were added to the global object?"

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention the context is in Node.js.

Comment: @MikeCheel Are you referring to [jslint](http://jslint.com)?

Comment: yes it usually helps me find stuff like this.

Comment: Your question's subject and the question do not correspond.  The subject appears to indicate that your question is about how to find out if the javascript files are being tempered with on client side. But then you real question appears to be related to coding issues in javascript (i.e., developer forgetting to declare a variable).  Anyway, in one of our apps that includes thousands of line of javascript, we put in place error logging in javascript side. Everytime there is an error in javascript, we capture it and send to the server.  We monitored the log for a few days.[continued]

Comment: [continued] we were able to find all issues with our javascript code and quickly fixed them. Perhaps it was easy for us because we had one main layout page that was being loaded for every refresh of the page.  So we just needed to put window.onerror at one place to capture all javascript errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES5’s [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) prevents this! Just put a `'use strict'` statement at the top of any function or source file:

```
'use strict';

function foo() {
    var x = 5   // Forgot the comma!
        y = 6;  // Fails in strict mode as an implicit global
}

foo();
```

Linters should also check for this, and you should use both a linter *and* strict mode, ideally. I recommend [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/).

Comment: Be warned strict mode isn't implemented consistently across browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: @MikeCheel: It’s for development. I hope nobody’s using IE≤9.

Comment: According to MDN it changes semantics and they aren't consistent across browsers.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation of strict mode and lint.  Both are excellent tools for finding silly mistakes.  For strict mode, you will have to decide whether you test with it in a good browser to find issues and then remove it and test again or whether you just leave it in and test with it in all supported browsers.  Personally, I want to develop and test my code only in strict mode.

Comment: It's always the most straight-forward answers that I forget, haha! Thanks minitech!

Comment: @MikeCheel: [citation needed]. MDN isn’t always right or current. (Also, we’re talking about Node.)